# This animation flickers at the end in IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a banner that animates through a few background images.  The animations are defined in CSS and triggered from JavaScript using the `triggerAnimation()` function in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHP9G/) and included below.  It works by animating the `next-banner` div on top of the `current-banner` div, and then updating the `current-banner` background to the new image after the animation finishes and resets.  The swap from the `next-banner` to the `current-banner` should be instantaneous, so that the user doesn't see it.

This works fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 11 it will occasionally flicker at the end of the animation.  It resets back to the beginning state of the animation before the `animationend` callback makes the swap, causing a noticeable flicker from the new image to the old one, and then back.  It happens unpredictably, and doesn't even seem to be consistent in how *often* it happens.  Sometimes it will happen almost every time, while others I'll have to wait through 5 or more transitions before seeing it.

There is evidence that it's caused by the `animationend` event firing late, because if I set a timeout to 50ms after the animation should have ended, and cancel that timeout in the `animationend` callback, then my timeout callback only executes when the flicker occurs, and doesn't execute when it behaves normally.

`triggerAnimation()` code:

```
window.triggerAnimation = function(element, animation, callback) {
    // omitted stuff to determine correct property and event names, which seems to work correctly
    element.style[propName] = animation;
    element.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
        element.style[propName] = "";
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, arguments.callee);
        if (callback) callback(e);
    }, false);
};
```

Is this a problem with my code or with IE, and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful for you or not but, I once was bothered by the same flickering you are complaining (it was in IE, mind-blown, right? ^^). Anyway, the way I solved it was to combine all the images into a sprite, set the background to the resulting image, and then every time I wanted to change the image I was actually updating the background-position to display the correct image in the sprite. This got rid of the flicker because the background was no longer being replaced, but rather it was showing a different region of itself.

Comment: @StefanBaiu Thanks for the suggestion, but I think we're talking about different issues.  What's flickering is not the background, but the animation.

Comment: hmmm, maybe increase the time for transition when you are in IE? sure the animation will take longer, but maybe it will seem smoother... just saying, I never liked working with animation in browsers anyway :)

Comment: Sounds very much like a bug in IE11, and might be difficult to resolve in JavaScript. I actually didn't see it at all when I watched your hypnotizing JSFiddle, so it's possible it's somewhat dependent on hardware/etc. (IE11 advertises that fancy CSS stuff is done on the GPU)

Comment: @Katana314 What OS were you using?  I've seen it happen on two different computers with Windows 8.1, but they also both have similar hardware.  I didn't see it after watching it for several minutes on a Windows 7 computer just now, but it also has substantially different hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've found to a solution is to set a timeout for just after when the animation should have finished, which "catches" the cases when IE doesn't fire the callback correctly.  Then, the actual event handler cancels the timeout for the cases when the callback is fired correctly.

So, this is what I've ended up with:

```
window.triggerAnimation = function(element, animation, callback) {
    // Omitted stuff to determine correct property and event names
    element.style[propName] = animation;

    // Extract the duration from the animation CSS and convert it to ms.
    var duration = parseFloat(animation.match(/\d+\.\d+/g)[0], 10) * 1000;

    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        element.style[propName] = "";
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, arguments.callee);
        if (callback) callback(null);
    }, duration + 10);
    element.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        element.style[propName] = "";
        element.removeEventListener(eventName, arguments.callee);
        if (callback) callback(e);
    }, false);
};
```

The only two downsides to this are: 1) it still will rarely flicker, but much less often and much less noticeably; and 2) any time that the timeout is invoked instead of the event handler, the event object (`e`) doesn't get passed to `callback`.  In my case that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to CSS file:

```
html {
    filter: expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this won't help.  The filter property was dropped in IE 10, and has nothing to do with CSS animations.